# Angular 2 unit tests: How do I test for the context menu and double click events?

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I just want this to work

```
 let fixture: any = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentBeingTested);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const contextMenuEl: DebugElement[] =  fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css("td"); 
        contextMenuEl[0].nativeElement.oncontextmenu();
        const doubleClickEl: DebugElement[] =  fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css("li"); 
        doubleClickEl[0].nativeElement.ondblclick();
```

When this is the template of the component:

```
<td (contextmenu)="contextMenuFunction">Context Menu</td>
<li (dblclick)="dblClickFunction">Double click</li>
```

I get the errors contextMenuEl[0].nativeElement.oncontextmenu is not a function and doubleClickEl[0].nativeElement.ondblclick is not a function

The app functionality works as expected. And yes, if I change these events to click in the template and in the test, it all works in the test.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to trigger a context menu change:

```
 contextMenuEl[0].triggerEventHandler("contextmenu", new  MouseEvent("contextmenu"));
 fixture.detectChanges();
```

This is how to trigger a double click change:

```
doubleClickEl[0].triggerEventHandler("dblclick", new MouseEvent("dblclick"));
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Comment: I got `triggerEventHandler is not defined` after trying this but `dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("contextmenu"))` worked for me in Angular 8. Can you explain the difference here?