# How to simulate double click event in angular 2 karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have html row element as so

```
<tr class="worktask" (click)="setCurrentTask($event, task)" (dblclick)="openTask($event, task)">some content</tr>
```

Now I want to test if openTask is called when some one double click on a row element in the table.

The way I am trying to do this is:

```
it('should be able to double click on a row to open work stream', async(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        comp.tasks=workflowServiceStub.getTasks(); //get dummy task
        fixture.detectChanges();                   // update view  based on dummy task
        spyOn(comp, 'openTask');                   //spy on openTask function if it is called
        let workTaskRow = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.worktask'); //getting task row

        workTaskRow[0].dblclick(); 
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
           expect(comp.openTask).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })
    }));
```

But when I run the test I get an error saying:

```
workTaskRow[0].dblclick is not a function
```

I tried .click() and it seem to work , not sure I can trigger a double click here to test if openTask() function is called.

Comment: the answer is there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537867/angular-2-unit-tests-how-do-i-test-for-the-context-menu-and-double-click-events

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the answer is there: [Angular 2 unit tests: How do I test for the context menu and double click events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537867/angular-2-unit-tests-how-do-i-test-for-the-context-menu-and-double-click-events)

```
const doubleClickEl: DebugElement[] =  fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css("li")); 

doubleClickEl[0].triggerEventHandler("dblclick", new MouseEvent("dblclick"));

fixture.detectChanges();
```